# A/V out of sync when using ffmpeg from mpeg-ts to dash

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, mpeg2-ts

I'm using ffmpeg in order to convert MPEG-TS stream to MPEG-DASH.
The mpeg-ts is h264 and aac_latm.
Therefore I don't need to reencode the video.
The command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i http://10.0.0.211:55555/Ch%2011%20Kan -strict -2 -c:v copy -window_size 10 -extra_window_size 10 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -f dash kan.mpd
```

I'm copying the video codec by using -c:v copy and the audio codec is default to aac.

That way I get DASH stream BUT the audio/video is out of sync!

How can I fix it?

Notes:

1. If I reencode both audio and video like:

   ffmpeg -i http://10.0.0.211:55555/Ch%2011%20Kan -strict -2 -window_size 10 -extra_window_size 10 -use_template 1 -use_timeline 1 -f dash kan.mpd

Then the audio/video is synced perfectly.
But I do not want to reencode the video for nothing as I mentioned the video is already h264. (directly impact to performance)

2. If I convert the MPEG-TS stream to mp4 file like:

   ffmpeg -i http://10.0.0.211:55555/Ch%2011%20Kan -strict -2 -c:v copy kan.mp4

Then the audio/video is synced perfectly.

Comment: Try adding `-af aresample=async=1`

Comment: thanks, but I tried it and it didn't help. any other ideas?